# Should I add my html code to index.html or App.js on my react app?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm just starting React and I'm confused on how to start adding my previous static website code into the react app. My react app contains a folder called public and a file in it called Index.html and it seems the changes in Index.html effect the website. But I've seen lots of videos and online forms where people add their website code into the App.js file located in src using JSX instead of the public folder.

I have 3 html files in my old static website and I'm wondering where to put the code from these files.

I also have node.js as the backend server but don't know if that should effect the answer.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider transforming the HTML code into JSX and make components out of it, that way your set up better for future changes.

If you want to keep as HTML code, you can implement it as an `<iframe src={"yourComponent"}/>` into your App.js.
Keep in mind that your HTML code should be stored in the public folder, the path that you put in the iframe will start at the *public folder*.

For example, you have a folder *html* in your public folder:

```
export default function YourComponent(){
    return <iframe src={"/html/yourcode.html"} />
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see... so should I touch index.html at all then? Seems like I don't really need it except the root part. I don't understand why it is needed other then that.

Comment: Well im not an expert, but to this day i didn't need to toucht it at all. At most sometimes when importing CSS files.